# Not expect when convert .ply file to .pcd file

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm converting a .ply file to .pcd file.
My .ply file's header is following:

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
element vertex 63194
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar blue
property uchar green
property uchar red
property uchar alpha
end_header
```

The output data is following:

```
VERSION 0.7VERSION 0.7
FIELDS x y z rgba
SIZE 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F U
COUNT 1 1 1 1
WIDTH 63194
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 63194
DATA ascii
-7734.2715 8366.3252 -2.1842694 0
-7734.5063 8366.3125 -1.9932992 0
-7733.0181 8366.3887 -2.20522 0
-7733.2417 8366.376 -2.0148311 0
-7731.7578 8366.4414 -2.2282174 0
```

I found that all agba is 0, however I can not found the code which decides the rgba value.
So my question is that how can I get the correct rgba?
Here is my test code

```
bool loadCloud (const std::string &filename, pcl::PCLPointCloud2 &cloud)
{
  pcl::PLYReader reader;
  if (reader.read (filename, cloud) < 0)
    return (false);
  return (true);
}

void saveCloud (const std::string &filename, const pcl::PCLPointCloud2 &cloud, bool format)
{
  pcl::PCDWriter writer;
  writer.write (filename, cloud, Eigen::Vector4f::Zero (), Eigen::Quaternionf::Identity (), format);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud;
  if (!loadCloud ("input.ply", cloud))
    return (-1);

  saveCloud ("output.pcd", cloud, false);

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Don't post links to code here please. Include it in your question instead.